# having trouble clicking in program - pyautogui

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I'm trying to click into a program window using pyautogui.

When clicking in the program window, on a button I wish to press, a loading icon appears next to the mouse cursor as if it is thinking, and it never actually clicks. It does, however, move to the cursor location that I provide.

Here's the code

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.doubleClick(x=300, y=300)
```

I opened Excel to see if it will click into that, and it does, but only if I run the code as:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.doubleClick(x=300, y=300)
pyautogui.doubleClick(x=300, y=300)
```

What the heck do I do?

Answer (score 3):

If the application in running as administrator and pyautogui script is not running as administrators, then control will not work. pyautogui script should also run as administrator to control it

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the interval argument

`pyautogui.doubleClick(x=300, y=300, interval=0.25)`