# Pyautogui library is not working properly on CMD program

Tags: python, cmd, automation, pyautogui

I am trying to automate a CMD program. I already opened on screen keyboard and "+" sign is located at (1874,919) location.

In the code shown here, I just simply move my cursor towards that location and click on the `+` sign. But it is not happening as per my expectation. Because according to my expectation when I press `+` sign it should open a window, but it is not opening and program does not throw any error, it just moves on to the next step.

This is my code:

```
pa.moveTo(1874,919, duration = 1) # move cursor towarsds + sign.
time.sleep(1)
pa.click(1874,919)  # clicking on + plus.
```

A window should open in that CMD program. By the way I tried the other library "pydirectinput" also.

Comment: I also tried "pa.press('+')" on that DOS program but it is also not working

Comment: Does [clicking twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959025/20103413) work? Or mousedown+sleep+mouseup according to another answer on the same page.

Comment: Which program is it? Can I test it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

So basically another library worked for me. **Keyboard** library.

```
keyboard.press('+')
```

this line of code worked for me.
Thanks everyone.